# Focus on page in login without using MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have login page based on MVVM and I try to call this.focus before I do proper login but the problem is that I have to click twice. First one just hide keyboard and give me information about missing username/password.

So probably the problem is connected with mvvm thing as fields are not updated when user clicks application bar button first.

I am new in MVVM so how can I do focus on page using it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I did it without MVVM. My application bar button handler below.

```
void Set_Details_MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            object focusObj = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
            if (focusObj != null && (focusObj is PasswordBox || focusObj is TextBox))
            {
                if (focusObj is PasswordBox)
                {
                    var binding = (focusObj as PasswordBox).GetBindingExpression(PasswordBox.PasswordProperty);
                    binding.UpdateSource();
                    viewModel.Login();
                }
                else if (focusObj is TextBox)
                {
                    var binding2 = (focusObj as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
                    binding2.UpdateSource();
                    viewModel.Login();
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                viewModel.Login();
            }
        }
```